# How to use a Bitmap as a Notification Icon

Tags: android, bitmap, notifications

I want to draw something on a pic , after do that , it is a Bitmap .  i want to add this Bitmap to the Notification as its icon. but it the icon must be a int Id .  How can i make it? thanks for your answer~~~~　pls hlep me!

Comment: What is the issue? Why toggling?

Answer (score 5):

From this [Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2059933/setting-an-android-notification-icon-to-a-remote-url) i came to know that Notification icon will take Resources image. So You cant do dynamic in Small icon. But you can do for large icon from Api Level 11.

For that you can use `Notificaiton.Builder` [Refer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11379518/android-change-notification-icon)

Other way is also there. That is you can change icon that appears when notification in pulled down. For that you have to Use `RemoteViews`

[Refer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7699119/custom-status-bar-notification-for-background-download)

Answer (score 2):

You can put image file in res->drawable (or drawable-hdpi,ldpi,mdpi), for example notify.png and use it

```
myNotification = new Notification(R.id.notify, "Notification!", System.currentTimeMillis());
```

or

Try using AnimationDrawable's. You can use them to combine multiple drawables into a single one, and select the one you want to display. I really think, this is the way to go.

More info: AnimationDrawable

Off course, you will have to provide individual drawables for all your Integers you want to display, but this way, you can easily change the appearance of your notifications

Answer (score 0):

convert you bitmap as a drawable and then you can use it as a notification icon in your dialog.

Comment: You cannot pass drawable only drawable's resource id as int

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
NotificationManager notificationManager=
            (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
int icon=R.drawable.ic_launcher;
CharSequence text="Notification Text";
long when=System.currentTimeMillis();

Notification notification=new Notification(icon, text, when);
notificationManager.notify(Constants.NOTIFICATION_ID, notification);
```

I have taken the default image you can keep image file in res->drawable (or drawable-hdpi,ldpi,mdpi) folder.Assign any bitmap to the icon and you will get desired output.

Answer (score 0):

try using xml draw your image, and put it in icon like n.icon = R.drawable.x;

drawable/x.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/write_normal_battery1" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/notif_0" android:left="5.5dip" android:right="13.5dip" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/notif_9" android:left="13.5dip" android:right="5.5dip" />
</layer-list>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Android Studio, you can always convert your original image to an Image Asset and that should generate the right image format that you can readily use, i.e. assign an ID. You can opt to overwrite the default resource name or have a different one.